# "Inspiration" meaning in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Taylors Swift's "inspiration" for (song name)

What does the inspiration here mean? And what's the whole thing mean? Could I get some examples, please? Does inspiration mean like artists have to get "inspiration" to get a wonderful work down; writer has to get "inspiration to get a wonderful work down?

That's the definition for inspiration

> 1.the process of being mentally stimulated to do or feel something, especially to do something creative:

Hmmm, what is being mentally stimulated?

Comment: Have you used a dictionary? This seems like it should be the most basic definition of the word. Please edit your question to include the dictionary definition you're using and explain what is confusing to you. :)

Comment: Ah could you give me the entry bcoz Ive really no idea what is the whole sentence mean ((

Comment: I'm sorry but we aren't a dictionary service. You need to do some basic definition research on your own.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, *inspiration* means something like

> thing or idea that was the source of influence [[1.]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspiration)

So it could be

> Taylor Swift's **idea that was the source of influence**  for (song name)...

I'm not familiar with her music, but I hear that a lot of her music deals with romantic relationships. So if we pretend the her source of influence was her last relationship, then the sentence could be

> Taylor Swift's **idea that was the source of influence**  for (song name) was her last relationship.

---

Mentally stimulated is having your brain or thoughts made active or influenced.
*Example.*
I just saw an interesting movie about space, stars, and the galaxy. I was mentally stimulated.

Comment: You are often mentally stimulating, but I think in this case you mean "I was mentally stimulated".

Comment: I was mentally perturbed. Haha, I guess my brain was split between "***It*** was mentally stimulating" and "I was mentally stimulated". What do you think is better?

Comment: Maybe both, just to drive the point home.